# Management API - Create VM - InvalidXmlRequest - The request body XML was invalid or not correctly specified

Tags: rest, azure, virtual-machine

I am getting error while creating virtual machine from Azure REST management API. Could someone please point me what wrong I am POSTing in below XML

ERROR ---  `<Error xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windowsazure" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><Code>InvalidXmlRequest</Code><Message>The request body's XML was invalid or not correctly specified.</Message></Error>`

My POST string:

```
"  <Deployment xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/windowsazure\" xmlns:i=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\">" + 
"    <Name>SomeName</Name>" + 
"    <DeploymentSlot>Production</DeploymentSlot>" + 
"    <Label>SomeLabel</Label>" + 
"    <RoleList>" + 
"      <Role>" + 
"        <RoleName>SomeRoleName</RoleName>" + 
"        <RoleType>PersistentVMRole</RoleType>" + 
"        <ConfigurationSets>" + 
"          <ConfigurationSet i:type=\"WindowsProvisioningConfigurationSet\">" + 
"            <ConfigurationSetType>WindowsProvisioningConfiguration</ConfigurationSetType>" + 
"            <ComputerName>SomeCompName</ComputerName>" + 
"            <AdminPassword>Admin098</AdminPassword>" + 
"            <EnableAutomaticUpdates>true</EnableAutomaticUpdates>" + 
"            <ResetPasswordOnFirstLogon>false</ResetPasswordOnFirstLogon>" + 
"          </ConfigurationSet>" + 
"          <ConfigurationSet i:type=\"NetworkConfigurationSet\">" + 
"            <ConfigurationSetType>NetworkConfiguration</ConfigurationSetType>" + 
"            <InputEndpoints>" + 
"              <InputEndpoint>" + 
"                <LocalPort>3389</LocalPort>" + 
"                <Name>RemoteDesktop</Name>" + 
"                <Protocol>tcp</Protocol>" + 
"              </InputEndpoint>" + 
"            </InputEndpoints>" + 
"          </ConfigurationSet>" + 
"        </ConfigurationSets>" + 
"        <OSVirtualHardDisk>" + 
"          <DiskName>SomeDiskName-0-20121007173943</DiskName>" + 
"          <MediaLink>http://portalvhdsrx7q659n2n5j2.blob.core.windows.net/public/myvhd0008980.vhd</MediaLink>" + 
"          <SourceImageName>MSFT__Win2K8R2SP1-Datacenter-201208.01-en.us-30GB.vhd</SourceImageName>" + 
"        </OSVirtualHardDisk>" + 
"        <RoleSize>Small</RoleSize>" + 
"      </Role>" + 
"    </RoleList>" + 
"  </Deployment>"
```

---

Hi,
Added AdminUsername also. But still getting error. DateTime of request - 04-11 17:30:03.759

```
<Error xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windowsazure" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><Code>InvalidXmlRequest</Code><Message>The request body's XML was invalid or not correctly specified.</Message></Error>
```

POST string

```
<Deployment xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windowsazure" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">    <Name>SomeName</Name>    <DeploymentSlot>Production</DeploymentSlot>    <Label>SomeLabel</Label>    <RoleList>      <Role>        <RoleName>SomeRoleName</RoleName>        <RoleType>PersistentVMRole</RoleType>        <ConfigurationSets>          <ConfigurationSet i:type="WindowsProvisioningConfigurationSet">            <ConfigurationSetType>WindowsProvisioningConfiguration</ConfigurationSetType>            <ComputerName>SomeCompName</ComputerName>            <AdminPassword>Admin098</AdminPassword>            <AdminUsername>AwesomeAdmin</AdminUsername>            <EnableAutomaticUpdates>true</EnableAutomaticUpdates>            <ResetPasswordOnFirstLogon>false</ResetPasswordOnFirstLogon>          </ConfigurationSet>          <ConfigurationSet i:type="NetworkConfigurationSet">            <ConfigurationSetType>NetworkConfiguration</ConfigurationSetType>            <InputEndpoints>              <InputEndpoint>                <LocalPort>3389</LocalPort>                <Name>RemoteDesktop</Name>                <Protocol>tcp</Protocol>              </InputEndpoint>            </InputEndpoints>          </ConfigurationSet>        </ConfigurationSets>        <OSVirtualHardDisk>          <DiskName>SomeDiskName-0-20121007173943</DiskName>          <MediaLink>http://portalvhdsrx7q659n2n5j2.blob.core.windows.net/public/myvhd0008980.vhd</MediaLink>          <SourceImageName>MSFT__Win2K8R2SP1-Datacenter-201208.01-en.us-30GB.vhd</SourceImageName>        </OSVirtualHardDisk>        <RoleSize>Small</RoleSize>      </Role>    </RoleList>  </Deployment>
```

Comment: Can you provide a tracking ID or exact timestamp for when you got this error?

Comment: Note- It is useful to provide a dump of the actual request body without all the code formatting. That's what the server sees, so it's the best thing to validate against the documentation.

Comment: What timezone is "04-11 17:30:03.759" in?  And can you provide the full server response which includes the x-ms-request-id?

Answer (score 1):

Try by adding `AdminUsername` node after `AdminPassword` node.

```
"  <Deployment xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/windowsazure\" xmlns:i=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\">" + 
"    <Name>SomeName</Name>" + 
"    <DeploymentSlot>Production</DeploymentSlot>" + 
"    <Label>SomeLabel</Label>" + 
"    <RoleList>" + 
"      <Role>" + 
"        <RoleName>SomeRoleName</RoleName>" + 
"        <RoleType>PersistentVMRole</RoleType>" + 
"        <ConfigurationSets>" + 
"          <ConfigurationSet i:type=\"WindowsProvisioningConfigurationSet\">" + 
"            <ConfigurationSetType>WindowsProvisioningConfiguration</ConfigurationSetType>" + 
"            <ComputerName>SomeCompName</ComputerName>" + 
"            <AdminPassword>Admin098</AdminPassword>" + 
"            <AdminUsername>AwesomeAdmin</AdminUsername>" + 
"            <EnableAutomaticUpdates>true</EnableAutomaticUpdates>" + 
"            <ResetPasswordOnFirstLogon>false</ResetPasswordOnFirstLogon>" + 
"          </ConfigurationSet>" + 
"          <ConfigurationSet i:type=\"NetworkConfigurationSet\">" + 
"            <ConfigurationSetType>NetworkConfiguration</ConfigurationSetType>" + 
"            <InputEndpoints>" + 
"              <InputEndpoint>" + 
"                <LocalPort>3389</LocalPort>" + 
"                <Name>RemoteDesktop</Name>" + 
"                <Protocol>tcp</Protocol>" + 
"              </InputEndpoint>" + 
"            </InputEndpoints>" + 
"          </ConfigurationSet>" + 
"        </ConfigurationSets>" + 
"        <OSVirtualHardDisk>" + 
"          <DiskName>SomeDiskName-0-20121007173943</DiskName>" + 
"          <MediaLink>http://portalvhdsrx7q659n2n5j2.blob.core.windows.net/public/myvhd0008980.vhd</MediaLink>" + 
"          <SourceImageName>MSFT__Win2K8R2SP1-Datacenter-201208.01-en.us-30GB.vhd</SourceImageName>" + 
"        </OSVirtualHardDisk>" + 
"        <RoleSize>Small</RoleSize>" + 
"      </Role>" + 
"    </RoleList>" + 
"  </Deployment>"
```

Comment: Hi Gaurav.. Still not working. Please check my edited text above.